# Cannot invite users via Google Play Services sharing

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

In [Google+ documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/interactive-post) for Android I've found following code for sharing interactive posts:

```
  PlusShare.Builder builder = new PlusShare.Builder(this);

  // Set call-to-action metadata.
  builder.addCallToAction(
      "CREATE_ITEM", /** call-to-action button label */
      Uri.parse("http://plus.google.com/pages/create"), /** call-to-action url (for desktop use) */
      "/pages/create" /** call to action deep-link ID (for mobile use), 512 characters or fewer */);

  // Set the content url (for desktop use).
  builder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/pages/"));

  // Set the target deep-link ID (for mobile use).
  builder.setContentDeepLinkId("/pages/",
          null, null, null);

  // Set the share text.
  builder.setText("Create your Google+ Page too!");

  startActivityForResult(builder.getIntent(), 0);
```

But it seems to me that this sample does not work. I see sharing dialog (with appropriate invitation indicator at the bottom) with pre-filled fields and I press share button at top-right corner. After that I receive success code in 'onActivityResult' method in my activity but when I open my Google+ page in desktop browser I do not see any invitation. I've tested code above on Samsung Galaxy Note 3 with Android 4.4.2. Version of Google Play Services is 4242000.

Also if I try to change example links to my own (for example https://github.com/) "Invite" indicator disappears from the bottom of share dialog and there is still nothing appears on my Google+ page.

Simple sharing without invitation works as it should. Can you help me to solve this trouble? Thanks you for any answer or idea.

Comment: I am working on same kind of application so have you some solution of your problem ? My question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505641/no-data-returned-in-intent-while-using-google

Comment: My problem was in old version of Google Play Services library