# No data returned in intent while using Google+

Tags: android, google-plus

I am working on an android application. I require following:

1.Post something on google plus.

2.After sometime **I want to count +1's and total shares of my post.**

I am doing it like this(**as suggested in samples given in android sdk**)

```
 String action = "/?view=true";
 Uri callToActionUrl = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_url) + action);
 String callToActionDeepLinkId = getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_id) + action;
    // Create an interactive post builder.
 PlusShare.Builder builder = new PlusShare.Builder(this, mPlusClient);
    // Set call-to-action metadata.
 builder.addCallToAction(LABEL_VIEW_ITEM, callToActionUrl, callToActionDeepLinkId);
    // Set the target url (for desktop use).
 builder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_url)));
    // Set the target deep-link ID (for mobile use).
 builder.setContentDeepLinkId(getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_id),
            null, null, null);
    // Set the pre-filled message.
 builder.setText(mEditSendText.getText().toString());
 Intent intent=  builder.getIntent();
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_INTERACTIVE_POST);
```

Every thing goes fine and I receive this dialogue to share and I can successful share my contents on google plus account

[image]

But Problem comes here as the dialogue dismiss my onActivityResult get called and I expect some url or postId of that post so that I can find it for some further processing

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
       // I am expecting some data in intent but intent is always null
    }
```

But **intent is always null**. So I just want to ask

1.**Is it possible to moniter a post, shared on google plus using android code ?(Yes / No)**

2.**If possible then what should I do ?**

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you :(, and I posted this issue in Google Plus Platform issue tracker, although I'm not optimistic of getting a response https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=959